# Azure Functions Fail if in Directory

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I've created a very simple durable function app for testing. It has 3 files (starter, orchestrator, activity) and a .csproj, along with the normal boilerplate (host.json, etc.)

When the 4 main files are in the root, the function works great. I'm using VS Code. I simply debug and "attach to C# functions".

If I move those 4 files to their own directory and register the `.csproj` with the `.sln` file, delete the `bin`/`obj` folders in root, I get an error.

```
chdir(2) failed.: No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

What do I need to do to tell Functions that my functions are one directory down?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. VS Code gets the command it runs from `.vscode/tasks.json`. There's one labeled "Run Functions Host". The `options.cwd` is the command it ends up running. You just need to add the directory in there

```
  "label": "Run Functions Host",
  "identifier": "runFunctionsHost",
  "type": "shell",
  "dependsOn": "build",
  "options": {
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/DIRECTORY_NAME/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0"
  },
```